# Javascript Switch - No Results, even Default?

Tags: javascript

Using Chrome's console/debugger:

In the if statement, quickChallengeResponse displays undefined

And console.dir(quickChallengeTimer) displays 30.

Yet on my page, **nothing is printed**, not even Error - and quickChallengeTimer isn't changed to 60, as it's told to do in case 30.

What's my mistake? Thanks.

```
var quickChallengeTimer = 30; var quickChallengeQuestion; 
var quickChallengeAnswer; var quickChallengeResponse;

    function quickChallenge(quickChallengeTimer, 
quickChallengeQuestion, quickChallengeAnswer) {

        if (typeof quickChallengeResponse == undefined) {
            switch (quickChallengeTimer) {

                case 30:
                    quickChallengeTimer = "60";
                    quickChallengeResponse = null;
                    console.write("now60");
                    break;

                case 60:
                    quickChallengeTimer = "120";
                    quickChallengeResponse = null;
                    console.write("now120");
                    break;

                default:
                console.write("Error");
                break;
            }
        }

        console.dir(quickChallengeTimer);
    }



quickChallenge(quickChallengeTimer);
```

Comment: The result of [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) will always be a string. The comparison should be against `'undefined'` (with quotes) instead of the [global variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

Comment: Jonathan, I just added the ' marks, and still: nothing is being displayed.

Comment: a big problem is that there is no such thing as  console.write()...

Comment: you can use " switch ( +quickChallengeTimer)" to compare against numbers in your cases, even if they are passed as strings. not a bad safety practice unless for some reason you need to be super-particular about types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typeof returns a string. You need to compare it against `'undefined'`

```
if (typeof quickChallengeResponse == 'undefined') {
            switch (quickChallengeTimer) {
```

Also, as pointed out in the comments, console.write doesn't exist. Use console.log

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cs2pLsx/1)

Comment: I meant to use document.write. Thanks!